# PARTITION BY in CASE doesn't work with several AND statements

Tags: sql, session, google-bigquery, partitioning

I have a table with 4 columns: hitId, userId, timestamp and Camp. 
I need to classify if a hit is a start of a new session or not (1 or 0) using two parameters: 1. the time difference between hits and 2. if the source of the hit is a new campaign.

I need a standard SQL query in BigQuery.

A hit is considered as a start of a new session if one of the following is true:

1. it's the first hit from its userId
2. the time difference between the timestamp of the previous hit from
   the same userId is more than 30 mins.
3. the time difference between the timestamp of the previous hit from the same userId is less than 30 mins, but Camp (ad campaign) value is not NULL and occures for the first time for the same userId within the previous 30 min.

So if hit1 from user1 has a Camp equal to Campaign1, and hit2 from user1 has a Camp equal to Campaign1, and time difference between hit1 and hit2 is less than 30 mins, hit1 will be considered as a start of a session, and hit2 won't be considered as a start.

I have a trouble with Campaign part. I tried this code:

I tried this code:

```
WITH timeDifference AS (
  SELECT *, 
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(timestamp, LAG(timestamp, 1) OVER
          (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY timestamp), SECOND) AS difference
    FROM hitTable
      ORDER BY timestamp)
SELECT *, 
  CASE 
  WHEN difference >= 30 * 60 THEN 1 
  WHEN difference IS NULL THEN 1 
  WHEN difference <= 30 * 60 AND Camp IS NOT NULL AND RANK() 
  OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY Camp) = 1 THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END AS sess
  FROM timeDifference
  ORDER BY timestamp;
```

The condition `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY Camp)` seems not working, as I receive this table:

```
hitId | userId |  timestamp   |  Camp           |  difference  |  sess
_______________________________________________________________________
00150 | 858201 | 00:48:35.315 |  NULL           |  NULL        |  1
00151 | 858201 | 00:49:35.315 |  NULL           |  5           |  0
00152 | 858201 | 00:50:35.315 |  Search-Ads-US  |  10          |  0
00153 | 858201 | 00:53:35.315 |  Search-Ads-US  |  15          |  0
00154 | 858202 | 00:54:35.315 |  Facebook-Ads   |  NULL        |  1
00155 | 858202 | 00:54:55.315 |  Facebook-Ads   |  9           |  0
00156 | 858202 | 00:57:20.315 |  Facebook-Ads   |  12          |  0
```

While I expect to have 1 for `sess` column for hitId = 00152:

```
hitId | userId |  timestamp   |  Camp           |  difference  |  sess
_______________________________________________________________________
00150 | 858201 | 00:48:35.315 |  NULL           |  NULL        |  1
00151 | 858201 | 00:49:35.315 |  NULL           |  5           |  0
00152 | 858201 | 00:50:35.315 |  Search-Ads-US  |  10          |  1
00153 | 858201 | 00:53:35.315 |  Search-Ads-US  |  15          |  0
00154 | 858202 | 00:54:35.315 |  Facebook-Ads   |  NULL        |  1
00155 | 858202 | 00:54:55.315 |  Facebook-Ads   |  9           |  0
00156 | 858202 | 00:57:20.315 |  Facebook-Ads   |  12          |  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY Camp) returns falsely results in cases where a user had multiple Camps.

Notice your PARTITION BY uses userId while you want to mark sessions within each Camp.

The actual "rank 1" of the RANK() (...) statement for userId 00150 is where the Camp is NULL (hitId 00150) therefore it misses your CASE condition at hitId 00152.

You could try and add 'Camp' to your PARTITION BY as follows:
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userId, Camp ORDER BY Camp)

Alternatively, you could replace the RANK() (...) and use LAG(Camp) (... order by timestamp) in addition to the LAG(timestamp) (...) you are calculating.
This will retrieve the Camp value for the row before (call it 'PreviousCampValue'). Then you could add something like WHEN PreviousCampValue != Camp THEN 1

Hope that's helpful

Comment: LAG(Camp) works exactly as needed. Thank you a lot for a detailed explanation!